# Neural Network predicting the same probability for each row

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've depeloped a 5 layers neural network for classification and it always predict the same probability for each row which ends predicting the same class.

I'm using Relu as activation fuction (if I use sigmoid or tanh it outputs NaN's) and `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`

The model will be this:

```
 X, Y = create_placeholders(n_x, n_y)

parameters = initialize_parameters()

Z5 = forward_propagation(X, parameters)

cost = cost_function(Z5, Y)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

And the prediction:

```
predicted = tf.nn.sigmoid(Z5)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.round(predicted), Y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

The cost value drops until 0.24, in the first 100 epochs, but the values predicted don't change.

[image: Prediction]

At the beginning I thought it was cause of an imbalance class problem but I fixed it (upsampling and wonsampling 1s and 0s) so it should not be the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you initialize your parameters randomly?

Comment: Yes I use `initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()` for W's and  `tf.zeros_initializer() ` for b's

Comment: If tanh or sigmoid become NaN, it means the value is too huge so the python cannot operate the exp(x) value in these two activations. In ReLU although it is less likely the NaN problem will happen, it is still likely that the neural network doesn't work normally. You should check the output and weights of each layer.

Comment: The first layer outputs all NaN's, the rest seem okey

Comment: Ok, I came here because I have the same problem. I was initializing the weights between [0, 1) and I changed it between [-1, 1) and it started working. Hope it is your case as well.

Comment: If the above comment does not resolve your issue, then you can try reducing the learning rate and increase the epochs so that model will learn. If you are using sigmoid for the last layer then restrict the output between (0,1).